# Best charting tool used in android for representing data of your app

Tags: android, graph

In my app, I have the following information which I want to display in the form of a graph.

1. Weight of a person.
2. Body temperature.
3. Date.

Now in my case, I want weight and body temperature on the y-axis parallel to each other and Date on the x-axis. So can anyone tell me which is the best android graph tool to do this? If possible with an example.

Regards
Anshuman

Answer (score 0):

I have done quiet a research on this.If you are looking for drawing pie,histograms, bar or line graphs with 3D look I beliver ther is not such library available.You can use [aichart](http://www.artfulbits.com/products/android/aicharts.aspx) for some 2D charts.Or final solution is you can start using the [google Chart APIS](https://developers.google.com/chart/) , they are very good but they all are in web view and you need to have internet available on the phone/emulator.

There is a [google group](http://groups.google.com/group/achartengine?pli=1) for [achartengine](http://www.achartengine.org/), lots of good code is floating around there you can join it.
But I am afraid you will not get the 3D charting anywhere else.
if you thought of using the [Adobe Flex](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=paTRLcmErNY) (using AIR 3.1 or higher) you may get tremendous fullfillment of the requirement you are having in your head.You may get tempted to use it at once,but teh programming is in AS(Action Script)
have a look at the linked video, you will get teh idea of what I am talking about, but sadly you have to code in Action Script and not in Andorid PL.